# How to I install a free NX server?

Tags: 11.10, freenx, neatx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I was trying to install it and I got something like this...

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can someone guide me through installing it on Ubuntu's latest?

Thanks,

Comment: community info here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) - looks like the freenx team has gone very very quiet since maverick.  You could use the community info and try to install on oneiric.  Tell us what you find out.

Comment: I tried but it seems like the repository does not work with Oneric,  (thats what the error above is from, trying to apt-get update before installing)

Comment: follow the guide i gave you - it shows how to tweak the install to install it on later versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing was installing the free Version of NoMachine NX Server, located hefer http://www.nomachine.com/select-package-server.php?id=1&ids=2

The free version is limited to 2 sessions but I figured that should be enough to cover my needs right now. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend x2go. It's based on NX, but the server is incompatible with FreeNX and Nomachine. But it has things like PulseAudio integration, which makes it a little nicer to play with since you can then use VoIP, etc. Just add `deb http://x2go.obviously-nice.de/deb/ lenny main` to your repos, update apt, and install x2goserver and then x2goclient on your client, from the same archive.

Comment: http://www.x2go.org/uploads/tx_skpdfviewer/installation_x2go_ubuntu_en.pdf I was following the tutorial and my server is not able to retrieve the key. Any help?
   gpg: requesting key 96F89133 from hkp server wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net

Comment: gpg: requesting key 96F89133 from hkp server wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Comment: They haven't signed it. Just ignore it and install it. It's generally a bad advise, but in this case.. Well. The world isn't perfect. :)

Comment: The X2go repository has migrated, use https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/stable instead.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script to compile and instal freenx server on Ubuntu 11.10. See my blog:

http://notepad2.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/install-freenx-server-on-ubuntu-1110.html

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team

sudo apt-get update

sudo aptitude install freenx
```

after that use nxsetup to install necessary files and create the special user “nx”
type these 
"sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install"
and if  you want to install opensource client for freenx use QTNX,QTNX NX client for QT install qtnx using the following command
"sudo apt-get install qtnx"