# The remote computer was reboot and i can't go in its autorun TeamViewer

Tags: 12.04, boot, login, autostart, teamviewer

The remote computer has a login/password and i want to save its procedure.

TeamViewer is running from autorun programs on a remote machine and gives me **free** access, but it does not start until the remote user logs in.

How can i solve it?
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Do you want to use Teamviewer or are you open to use another remote access solution?.

Comment: I think i want to use it. But i am ready to read about another applications.

Comment: do you have ssh access to that computer? im using this command  ssh -X -C -c blowfish user@ipadress -p port "teamviewer" to start teamviewer remotely

Comment: I can install ssh sever on remote comp, but what about ip address and port? There is router at the office. Is ip address external or internal?

Comment: normally by default it use port 22. if you not in local network then use public ip.

Comment: Remote comp is in office's local network. Is there problem in this case? Can i connect to internal (local) ip of remote computer from Internet? As i know public ip is ip of router, not of remote local, is't it?

Comment: yes the machine need to connect to internet or you on same local network

Comment: the remote computer is connected to Internet, but i afraid i can not connect to its local ip. Can i?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if TeamViewer will allow that, most desktop sharing apps will only work then one user is connected, including the Ubuntu bundled one.

[FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) is a remote desktop server than can be useful for you. It will ask you for a username and password and open a **new** session with that user. It's tunnelled under ssh, quite fast and very secure. But it's not as near as easy to configure (read convenient) as TeamViewer: You will need to install the server, install a client on the computers where you are going to connect from, and open port 22 on your router. See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71691/how-to-i-install-a-free-nx-server) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27320/how-do-i-install-freenx-server-so-that-it-works-correctly).

Note that after the pain it works really well, we used it at work for a couple of years to let around 20 computers access our server through low-speed ADSL lines and we were very happy with it.

Comment: Thank you,my friend. This solution would be good alternative!